# Можно ли сократить код? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Можно ли сократить код? Если да, то как?

```
function sort(a,b){
  var c = a.time -b.time;
  if (c < 0){
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
function sort(a,b){
   return(a.time>b.time)?true:false;
}
```

Или так:

```
function sort(a,b) { 
    return a.time > b.time;
}
```

Или так:

```
const sort = (a,b)=>a.time > b.time;
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
function sort(a,b) { 
    return a.time > b.time;
}
```